# Java is unavailable for the hp loadrunner tutorial

Tags: loadrunner

I am using the trial version of HP LoadRunner (v12).

On the flights page of the  tutorial

```
http://localhost:1080/WebTours/index.htm
```

I getting the error the Java is unavailable. Though I have installed the Java. The issue is around the departure and return dates. I have tried to use this tutorial using different browsers (IE11,FF,Chrome,Safari) but the problem is the same. I am using Windows 7 on 64 bit machine.

(IE11 could be of 32 bit but the rest of the browsers are 64 bit)

Comment: Did you restart LoadRunner after you installed Java? I doubt a web-browser is giving you that error, but perhaps you could post the entirety of the actual error.

Comment: Application Blocked

Application Blocked by Security Settings

Name:FormDateUpdate

   Location: http://localhost:1080

Your security settingd have blocked an untrusted application from running

Comment: The error is not thrown by the loadrunner but by the web browser when I run the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

LoadRunner is a 32 bit product.  If you have 64 bit Java then you are out of luck.   Please see all installation notes regarding the use of LoadRunner in 64 bit environments.

There is no trial version of LoadRunner version 12.  There is a non expiring community edition, but there is no trial, trail rated, evaluation, POC, etc...   There are still training & production licenses available for purchase.

Comment: The loadrunner works fine on my 64 bit machine. The problem is with one of the pages of the loadrunner tutorial. As mentioned earlier also, its the web browser that's giving the error and not the loadruuner.

Comment: Please read the installation notes regarding 32 and 64 bit environments